# Finding which words matched a MySQL Match-Against query

Tags: c#, mysql, match-against

In my C# application I'm running a search against a MySQL DB for items matching keywords defined by the user.
An example query looks like this:

```
SELECT * from records WHERE MATCH(body) AGAINST ('"some words" "more words" "singleword"')
```

I would like to determine for each result the word(s) that matched. 
I would like to avoid writing more code to search each result returned by the DB in order to determine the matches.
I'm considering altering the query to use IN BOOLEAN MODE - and in that case it might become more difficult to perform the search.

Is there any way I can get the matched words from MySQL?

Comment: why you dont use LIKE statement ?

Comment: Molderf - I'm not using LIKE because I want to match whole words only, and I would like the option to use IN BOOLEAN MODE.
Soner - I'm not sure I understand how IN would help me, can you elaborate?